# How to get Discussion actived and deactive of creator in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I want get discussion actived and deactive of creator in course.I did this but did not:

admin, teacher ok but user and student then it took `orwhere` `parent_id != 0`

```
 $builder = Discussion::with('user')
    ->where('deleted_at', null)
    ->where('parent_id', 0)
    ->where('cou_id', $cou_id)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');

if ($my_role == 'admin') {
    $data = $builder->simplePaginate($pageSize);
} elseif ($my_role == 'teacher') {
    $data = $builder->where('type', 0)->simplePaginate($pageSize);
} else {
    $data = $builder->where('active', 1)->where('type', 0)
        ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($user) {
            $query->where('active', 0)->where('type', 1)->where('user_id', $user->id);
        })->simplePaginate($pageSize);
}
```

Comment: You question is unclear can you add plain sql in your question for your different criteria or at least specify which criteria will be followed for each role

Comment: At `else` I want to take out the active discussion of other members and discuss the creator himself without being approved by the admin